# Using Fourier cosine/sine integral , compute an integration

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

For all $x>0$, show that

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{w^3 \cos(w x)}{w^4 +4} dw = \frac{\pi}{2} e^{-x}\sin(x)$$

I want to solve this problem using Fourier integral, but it is too hard for me.

Comment: btw...the result  is wrong

Comment: @tired Seriously??

Comment: take $x=0$: the rhs equals $0$ whereas the lhs doesn't even exist. by continuation to finite but small x you see that something is fishy here

Comment: We just show that the case $x>0$

Comment: see my extended comment

Comment: What does it mean? I couldnt understand.

Comment: A similar formula is $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{w^3 \sin(w x)}{w^4 +4} dw = \frac{\pi}{2} e^{-x}\cos(x)$. This one is true.

Comment: @Aforest I also know the formula, but when I calculate this one, the equation does not hold

Comment: Read more here： http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94442

Comment: I tried it, but I guess the result is wrong. I think $-2w^2 + 2$ is true instead of $w^3$